# Dynamic RLS With Multiple Columns in User Table

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to create a dynamic rls , Here is my RLS code

```
VAR _CurrentUserEmail = USERPRINCIPALNAME()

VAR _AllowedRegions = 
CALCULATETABLE(
    VALUES(Region_Permission[Region]),
    Region_Permission[Email] = _CurrentUserEmail
)

VAR _AllowedProjects = 
CALCULATETABLE(
    VALUES(Region_Permission[Project]),
    Region_Permission[Email] = _CurrentUserEmail
)

VAR _AllowedGroups = 
CALCULATETABLE(
    VALUES(Region_Permission[Group]),
    Region_Permission[Email] = _CurrentUserEmail
)

VAR _Roles = 
CALCULATE(
    VALUES(Region_Permission[Role]),
    Region_Permission[Email] = _CurrentUserEmail
)

VAR _RLS_Restriction =
IF (
    _Roles IN  "Region" && [WH_Region] IN _AllowedRegions,
    TRUE(),
    IF (
        _Roles IN "Project" && [WH_Project] IN _AllowedProjects,
        TRUE(),
        IF (
            _Roles IN "Group" && [Agent_Group_Name] IN _AllowedGroups,
            TRUE(),
            IF (
                _Roles IN "Region-Project" && [WH_Region] IN _AllowedRegions && [WH_Project] IN _AllowedProjects,
                TRUE(),
                IF (
                    _Roles IN "Region-Group" && [WH_Region] IN _AllowedRegions && [Agent_Group_Name] IN _AllowedGroups,
                    TRUE(),
                    IF (
                        _Roles IN "Project-Group" && [WH_Project] IN _AllowedProjects && [Agent_Group_Name] IN _AllowedGroups,
                        TRUE(),
                        IF (
                            _Roles IN "Region-Project-Group" && [WH_Region] IN _AllowedRegions && [WH_Project] IN _AllowedProjects && [Agent_Group_Name] IN _AllowedGroups,
                            TRUE(),
                            FALSE()
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

RETURN
    _RLS_Restriction
```

Also Role column i have created with this dax

```
Role = 
VAR regionname = [Region]
VAR Project = [Project]
VAR _group = [Group]

VAR _Role =
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    regionname <> BLANK() && Project = BLANK() && _group = BLANK(), "Region",
    regionname = BLANK() && Project <> BLANK() && _group = BLANK(), "Project",
    regionname = BLANK() && Project = BLANK() && _group <> BLANK(), "Group",
    regionname <> BLANK() && Project <> BLANK() && _group = BLANK(), "Region-Project",
    regionname <> BLANK() && Project = BLANK() && _group <> BLANK(), "Region-Group",
    regionname = BLANK() && Project <> BLANK() && _group <> BLANK(), "Project-Group",
    regionname <> BLANK() && Project <> BLANK() && _group <> BLANK(), "Region-Project-Group",
    "Other"
)
RETURN
    _Role
```

When a user has a single value passed from a range (i.e., a value in any of the three columns and the rest two columns are blank). The RLS works in this case. However, if I want to add a region or project for that user, it gives an error.

The error message I'm receiving is "The function expects a table instead of a string or numeric expression." Or sometimes if i change some context it was saying multiple values supplied where single value was expected.

Any help or insights on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Any help or insights on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Just for the context here i am filtering "Tickets" table which contain Tickets[WH_region],Tickets[WH_Project] and Tickets[Agent_Group_Name]